# Google sheets to firebase

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get my table data to my firestore app but such error
keep showing :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null (line 14, file "Code")

I've done all configuration and I added Firestore library to Apps Script

```
function covidFunc() {
   const email = "myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com";
   const key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

   const projectId = "my project id";
   var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);
  
  
  // get document data from ther spreadsheet
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetname = "US-covid";
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 
   // get the last row and column in order to define range
   var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); // get the last row 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check again if your active spreadsheet; the one you have this project attached to, has a sheet/tab with the name : "US-covid".

Comment: I did yes it has the same name

Comment: can you also attach a screenshot that shows the name of the tab and some data of this tab maybe?

Comment: ok I wrote just one line for testing 
https://ibb.co/31zF18x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your active spreadsheet file; the one that your google apps script project is attached to, should have a tab/sheet with the name: `US-covid`. Your screenshot just provides a spreadsheet file with the name US-covid. But a **tab/sheet** should have it.

Example:

[image: explanation]